# Finding which Google account an API Key is associated with

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform

I've been asked to help with a site using Google's mapping APIs (mainly Maps Javascript) and we can see the API key on the site but we have been unable to trace which Google account this is associated with. I can set up a new account and a new key and then change the site code, but with another site I have worked on Google had applied a very hefty transition credit after the recent billing changes, plus having the original account access will allow me to see historic usage stats and work out potential future costs under the new allowances.

I realise it would be a security/privacy breach to just reveal the email, but is there any way anyone knows that you can enter an API key and for example have it send a password reset or similar email to the account email address?

Comment: Try to talk with Google maps platform support team. An API key is related to project, but they won't reveal this information unless you are a project member.

Answer (score 0):

API keys are not associated to google accounts. An API key only identifies the project associated to the call for [billing and quota](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) purposes (and of course to allow or deny the resource). You cannot “reset” an API Key but you can create a new one.